# How to log into Facebook without the Facebook app?

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I use a Facebook sample app (`SessionLoginSample`) to understand how to log into Facebook. My Facebook SDK is latest — [version 3.0](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0). When I have the Facebook app installed, I can log in without any problems.

The problem is when I uninstall my Facebook app and re-install the sample (so it doesn't log in automatically). I try to log in but I can see only a white empty dialog. The only option I have is to close it. Even if I wait 10-15 minutes, the dialog doesn't change.

[image: SessionLoginSample - Login]

I tried to debug the Facebook SDK but I couldn't find what's causing the error.

I tested this on LG-E610 (4.0.3) and HTC Sensation (4.0.3).

Is this facebook sdk error or I'm doing something wrong?

**Edit:** I tested this issue again 10 days later in the same coditions and everything seems to work  as expected.

Comment: Try enabling debug logs for Facebook by using something like : Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.REQUESTS); You can find many other options for LoggingBehavior. It should point and tell you what's happening in the back end.

Comment: Could you resolve the issue?

Comment: Today I tested this with different WIFI network and the dialog was working good. I have to do more test and then I'll post the information here.

Comment: that's interesting. I also found that the accessing network seem to matter. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589114/facebook-web-login-in-android-app-stalls-when-using-wifi-instead-of-3g

Comment: @robert, see my last edit. I can not reproduce this issue anymore.

Comment: But I had this problem just now, which speaks against the fb-fixed-bug theory. Also, I did tests within minutes and it depended on the IP/user agent combination only. Are you using a dynamic IP? - maybe it changed. Mine changed (reassigned by provider) and now the problematic network works too.

Comment: Yes, my IP is dynamic. Maybe it changed and that's the reason I have no problems now. If you resolve this issue, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might not be on your side! I have encountered a situation where one and the same request to Facebook would be answered as expected or with an "Internal Server Error 500" depending on my IP (IP/User agent to be exact).

You can be quite certain that nothing is wrong with your configuration and application when:

1. Your app works from another network (i.e. another IP)
2. When the sample app from Facebook (i.e. HelloFacebookSample) runs into the same problem.

   - For Android see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/
   - For iOS see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/

My suspicion is that Facebook puts certain IP/user agent combinations in a temporary black list. The problem is that their generic 500 response is not helpful.

For another reported case see my question at [Internal Server 500 from Facebook with sepcific IP/user-agent combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589114/facebook-web-login-in-android-app-stalls-when-using-wifi-instead-of-3g)