# Internal Server 500 from Facebook with sepcific IP/user-agent combination

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, ip, block

I am running the android app HelloFacebookSample from Facebook on my phone.

The native Facebook app is NOT installed.

When I try to login via my WiFi network the login process stalls at >
D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(6404): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=touch&client_id=XXX38988221028&scope=&type=user_agent&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess
<

...and all I get is this blank white dialog popup with the close button (x) in the upper left corner.

So far so bad, but when I switch off the wireless on my phone and force a connection via 3G it works.

I know it sounds crazy but that's how it is. If I switch to Wi-Fi it stalls, with 3G it works again.

If I put the "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/..." url in mobile Chrome I get an Internal Server Error 500 when I am on Wi-FI and I get the expected login page when I am on the 3G.

Now I am just looking for ideas as to why this could be so.

- Could it be that Facebook is blocking my IP? (Id did many repeated tests, allowing, removing the app etc.)
- NOTE: The "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/..." url works from my desktop browser over said Wi-Fi connection. So if there was blocking of any kind it would have to be against a combination of IP and user agent.

**UPDATE**: I also tried it from another Wi-Fi network and it worked as expected. So it really seems that I got a specific "Internal Server 500" from Facebook from that IP/device?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason in my case must have been the IP/User-Agent combination that was blacklisted by Facebook:

When I tried with the same device from another Wi-Fi network (i.e. with another IP) then the connection to Facebook worked as expected.

Or if I used the same Wi-Fi with another User-Agent (i.e. other browser) then it worked as expected too.